# How to build only css files from sass using sencha command?

Tags: extjs, sass, compass-sass, sencha-command

is there an easy way to build only css files from sass files in extjs project without running the whole build process? I know I could create a config file for compass and use `compass watch` but isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: You don't need any config file, just start "compass watch" in your sass folder while developing.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. 
"Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
Run "compass -h" to get help."

Comment: Sorry, you have to run it in your main project folder, not in your sass folder.

Comment: Still doesn't work, "Nothing to compile....."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to use the command "sencha ant sass" to recompile the CSS using Sass. With Sencha Cmd 4 the command "sencha app watch" will also recompile CSS when needed.

Note that simply running "compass watch" no longer works with Ext JS 4.2 since the theme structure changed.

Source: http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-the-new-app-watch-command-in-sencha-cmd-4/

Comment: `sencha ant sass` still works with cmd 6.5. Add `development` as `sencha ant development sass` to generate a readable .css